# \tkzMarkRightAngle produces "Missing \endcsname"

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I'm making a chart that has a triangle on it. I want to show that this triangle has a right angle in it, and I discovered `\tkzMarkRightAngle` can be used to achieve this effect. `\tkzMarkAngle` also works but for this particular image I need the former, not the latter. Unfortunately, using it only gives me an error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
   <to be read again> 
                      \tkz@ax 
   l.18 ...rkRightAngle[draw=black,size=0.4cm](H,G,I)
```

So here's my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[x11names,dvipsnames]{xcolor} %Colocação de cores
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot} %Para fazer desenhos
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (G) at (3,0);
\coordinate (H) at (5,0);
\coordinate (I) at (3,2);

\draw (G) -- (H) -- (I) -- cycle;

\tkzMarkRightAngle[draw=black,size=0.4cm](H,G,I)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Please note that `\tkzMarkAngle` works perectly, but it doesn't do the mark that I want. What would be the correct way to get it to work?

Comment: Please add a document class so your code can be compiled.

Comment: Thanks, @cfr, I had forgotten to copy that. I tried it with both `article` and `standalone` classes, and since it's just the image, I left the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't read French, but the examples in the manual suggest that you need to define your points appropriately before you can use `\tkzMarkRightAngle`. For example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(3,0){G}
  \tkzDefPoint(5,0){H}
  \tkzDefPoint(3,2){I}
  \draw (G) -- (H) -- (I) -- cycle;
  \tkzMarkRightAngle(H,G,I)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: right-angled triangle]

Although `tkz-euclide` is based on TikZ, that does not mean that a TikZ macro which superficially has a similar effect to a `tkz` macro can be used as a drop-in replacement or *vice-versa*. As you note, `\coordinate` allows you to perform coordinate calculations with the `calc` library, whereas `\tkzDefPoint` might not.

Here is the definition of `\tkzDefPoint` from `tkz-obj-points.tex`.

```
\def\tkzDefPoint{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkzActivOff\tkz@DefPoint}{%
                                      \tkzActivOff\tkz@DefPoint[]}}
```

OK, so we need to look at `\tkz@DefPoint`.

```
\def\tkz@DefPoint[#1](#2)#{% 
\tkz@parsecoordinate{#2}
\iftkz@polar
 \tkz@ptStar[polar](\tkz@polarangle,\tkz@polarrad){tkz@coord@temp}
 \else  
     \tkz@ptStar[](#2){tkz@coord@temp}
 \fi
\tkz@DefPointEnd[#1]}%
```

`\tkz@DefPointEnd` calls `\coordinate`. But before that, the code also calls `\tkz@ptStar` (for a Cartesian coordinate).

```
\def\tkz@ptStar[#1](#2,#3)#{%
\pgfkeys{/tkzpt/.cd,
 polar     = false,%
} 
\pgfqkeys{/tkzpt}{#1}  
\iftkz@pt@polar%
  \FPeval\tkz@x{(#3*cos(#2*\FPpi/180))}
  \FPeval\tkz@y{(#3*sin(#2*\FPpi/180))}
\else
  \FPeval\tkz@x{(#2)}
  \FPeval\tkz@y{(#3)}
\fi
\FPadd{\ptxa}{\tkz@x}{-\tkz@init@xorigine}
\FPadd{\ptya}{\tkz@y}{-\tkz@init@yorigine}
\FPdiv{\ptxa}{\ptxa}{\tkz@init@xstep}
\FPdiv{\ptya}{\ptya}{\tkz@init@ystep}
\tkz@node
}
```

This saves a bunch of information about the point which can then be accessed by other macros such as `\tkzMarkRightAngle`.

The crucial point is that `tkz-euclide` is a system built on top of TikZ. Its commands are designed to work together within that system.

You can use regular TikZ stuff as well, but you cannot typically use a TikZ macro and then use a `tkz-euclide` macro which builds on it as the latter will assume you've used the `tkz-euclide` macros which set things up within the `tkz-euclide` system.

You can, however, use TikZ methods for manipulating coordinates, for example, with `tkz-euclide` points because `tkz-euclide` executes `\coordinate` when defining them. For example, the `calc` library will happily work with this species.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(3,0){G}
  \tkzDefPoint(5,0){H}
  \tkzDefPoint(3,2){I}
  \draw (G) -- (H) -- (I) -- cycle;
  \tkzMarkRightAngle(H,G,I)
  \draw ($(H)!1/2!(G)$) -- ($(G)!1/2!(I)$) -- ($(I)!1/2!(H)$) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: calculate with tkz points]

Comment: Using the `\coordinate` command would allow me to create coordinates like `H = G + (2,0)` with the code `\coordinate (H) at ($(G)+(2,0)$)`, but that wouldn't be possible with `\tkzDefPoint`, would it? I have coordinates adjusted like that in my main file.

Comment: Well, you asked how to use `\tkzMarkRightAngle`. The examples I found use `\tkzDefPoint`. I never use `tkz-euclide` myself. Do you have any reason to think it is meant to work the way you want?

Comment: Just thought it could work, I was thinking `tkz-euclide` was based on `tikz`

Comment: It is based on TikZ, but `\tkzDefPoint` is not a drop-in replacement for `\coordinate`, as you noticed. Likewise, `\coordinate` is not a drop-in replacement for `\tkzDefPoint`. `\tkzMarkRightAngle` assumes that the code in the definition of `\tkzDefPoint` has been executed for the relevant points. If it hasn't, it may or may not work, but you certainly shouldn't expect it to work or to continue working.

Comment: @GuilhermeVargas Please see edit. `calc` works fine for me with `tkz-euclide` points. This is expected because `\tkzDefPoint` executes `\coordinate`, which is all `calc` needs. It is just that it does a bunch of other stuff first, which `\tkzMarkRightAngle` needs as well. So if you use `\tkzDefPoint`, you can use both `\tkzMarkRightAngle` and coordinate calculations with `calc`.